# Comparing hex in C

Tags: c, if-statement, types, nfc

*Context: I'm wanting to test the Uid from a Mifare card using libnfc. I have taken apart this example: http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libnfc:quick_start_example*

print_hex is a helper function at the top of the linked example, it is this:

```
print_hex(const uint8_t *pbtData, const size_t szBytes)
{
  size_t  szPos;

  for (szPos = 0; szPos < szBytes; szPos++) {
    printf("%02x  ", pbtData[szPos]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

I can output the UID of a card like this:

```
print_hex(nt.nti.nai.abtUid, nt.nti.nai.szUidLen);
```

And this is what I get:

```
9f  d8  a2  00
```

I'd like to compare that against a stored value, something like:

```
if (*nt.nti.nai.abtUid == 0x9fd8a200) {
```

but that gives me the warning:

```
reader.c:81:28: warning: comparison of constant 2681774592 with expression of type 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') is always false [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
    if (*nt.nti.nai.abtUid == 0x9fd8a200) {
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I change to:

```
if ((int)*nt.nti.nai.abtUid == 0x9fd8a200) {
```

It compiles but does not match, and if I change to:

```
if (nt.nti.nai.abtUid == 0x9fd8a200) {
  printf("Winner\n");
}
```

it gives a warning of:

```
reader.c:81:27: warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') and 'unsigned int')
    if (nt.nti.nai.abtUid == 0x9fd8a200) {
```

Assistance appreciated!

**Edit**

This is what worked:

```
 const uint8_t winner[] = { 0x9f, 0xd8, 0xa2, 0x00};
 if (memcmp(nt.nti.nai.abtUid, winner, 4) == 0) {
   printf("Winner\n");
 }
```

Comment: @Deduplicator can I use memcmp() when one of the objects is not a pointer? Can you give an example? Also the number of bytes may change.

Comment: Obviously you need transform both to the same format, using `print_hex` or whatever. Maybe even at/beforecompile-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how the ID against which you want to compare is stored.
This:

```
0x9fd8a200
```

right now is just a 4 byte integer. But you said nr. of bytes can change?

It is best I think if you store the ID against which  you want to compare as byte array, e.g.,

```
const uint8_t id[] = { 0x9f, 0xd8, 0xa2, 0x00};
```

Then you can just `memcmp` this with `abtUid`.

Comment: @SimonJGreen: nice if it helped. You can also initialize id[] with a 7 byte array - and use memcmp, I think some IDs of mifare are also 7 bytes long.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ((int)*nt.nti.nai.abtUid == 0x9fd8a200) {
```

This is still an 8-bit quantity, but converted to `int`. What you need is to access the region as a 4x8-bit quantity. This can be done by type-punning (eg. what BLUEPIXY has suggested), but there is no guarantee (visible in your code) that the `abtUid` is suitably aligned for 32-bit memory access. On some processors, this may cause a bus-error.

Instead, you can use `memcmp()` to compare the Uid's. Eg:

```
memcmp (nt.nti.nai.abtUid, "\x9f\xd8\xa2\x00", 4)
```